# Is it recommended to use embedded elasticsearch for running tests on an application?

Tags: elasticsearch, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

The application, in general, uses a separately managed elasticsearch cluster, but for tests, we are planning to use an embedded server. Is it advisable to do so?

Comment: You might want to read this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/integration-tests.html

Comment: Thanks for that, we are aware that we can spin up a separate cluster, but we want to know why an embedded server can/can't be used.